# Set value to a variable that needs a replace and result of if, is it possible in one line?

Tags: scala

Sorry newbie question, I'm learnig scala

So i got a href say href="www.bbc.co.uk/", and i want to get rid of the href and /. whats the most conside way of doing it?

This is what i got so far

```
var cleandUpUrl = "href=".r.replaceFirstIn(urls, "").replace("\"", "")
cleandUpUrl = if(cleandUpUrl.endsWith("/")) cleandUpUrl.dropRight(1) else cleandUpUrl
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
val cleandUpUrl = if ("href=".r.replaceFirstIn(urls, "").replace("\"", "").endsWith("/")) _.dropRight(1) else _
```

Somehow return the value created inside the if.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you probably don't want to do that. Parsing HTML with regexps is a world of hurt. Instead, an approach like this, perhaps? http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-html-parsing

Comment: Yea I mainly just wanted to do it to learn how to do it, I won't normally mess about with xml myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `replaceAll` with regex `href=|/` which matches either *href=* or */*:

```
val urls = "href=\"www.bbc.co.uk/\""
// urls: String = href="www.bbc.co.uk/"

urls.replaceAll("href=|/", "")
// res106: String = "www.bbc.co.uk"
```

---

Suppose you just want to replace the trailing */*, you can use look ahead syntax to replace the */* right before *"*:

```
urls.replaceAll("href=|/(?=\")", "")
// res111: String = "www.bbc.co.uk"

val urls = "href=\"www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/sports = www.bbc.co.ukiplayersports\""
// urls: String = href="www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/sports = www.bbc.co.ukiplayersports"

urls.replaceAll("href=|/(?=\")", "")
// res113: String = "www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/sports = www.bbc.co.ukiplayersports"
```

Comment: that would replace all / no? so www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/sports = www.bbc.co.ukiplayersports. I'd only want to replace the trailing /

Comment: Yes. Do you want to replace just the trailing */*?

Comment: I just feel cleandupurl should be a val, but because it's 2 operations, it needs to be a var.

Comment: yea, just the trailing /

Comment: You will always have a url with extra quotes though.

Comment: ended up with this.       val cleandUpUrl : String = "href=".r.replaceFirstIn(urls, "").replace("\"", "") match {
        case url: String if (url.endsWith("/")) =>  url.dropRight(1).toString
        case url: String =>  url
      }